# IN MYSQL, SUM ALL VALUES IN

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table called 'articulo' and column called CostoPromedio, I Want to SUM this column by the id , I'm getting this ID's from PHP, I'm inserting these on the query:

```
INSERT INTO dbName.venta (tMoneda,idTipoDeDocumento,total) VALUES(11,32,(SELECT SUM(CostoPromedio) FROM dbName.articulo WHERE idArticulo IN (15, 16,15,17,16))
```

The problem is is adding 15,16,17, but in the repeated ID is not adding  the result, is just ignoring him, I want adding all, including if is the same ID.

Sorry about my english, is not my native language

Comment: `WHERE idArticulo IN (15, 16, 15, 17, 16)` is the same as saying `WHERE idArticulo IN (15, 16, 17)` - duplicates are ignored. Do you want to add twice if it's 15, twice if it's 16, and once if it's 17?

Comment: Yes, i don't want ignore duplicates. I want take duplicates and insert too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've missed a braket at last. And remove duplicates in 'IN' clause.

```
INSERT INTO dbName.venta (tMoneda,idTipoDeDocumento,total) 
VALUES(11,32,(SELECT SUM(CostoPromedio) 
              FROM dbName.articulo 
              WHERE idArticulo IN (15,16,17)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use `INSERT INTO ..SELECT...FROM` as the query:

```
INSERT INTO dbName.venta (tMoneda,idTipoDeDocumento,total) 
SELECT 11, 32, SUM(CostoPromedio) 
FROM dbName.articulo
WHERE idArticulo IN (15, 16, 17)
```